# Application crashes only in release version

Tags: java, android, apk, release, android-6.0-marshmallow

When you run the application in **debug** mode the app can't crash. But when generates the .apk file **release** the app crash. **This error does not happen on all phones**, in just a few that have the android 6.

The logcat shows that the problem is a **NullPointerException** in the  class (**android.support.v4.widget.drawerlayout**). How can a NullPointerException launches only on release apk?

We already disable proguard, minify and shrinkResources. Didn't resolve this bug.

Here some logs:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.WindowInsets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft()' on a null object reference
  at android.support.v4.widget.i.a(Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$d.a(Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)    
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
```

Comment: Can you put some of code of the drawer layout

Comment: Are you sure, that you disable minify for release version? It looks like you still have enabled proguard: 
at android.support.v4.widget.i.a
i.a it is obfuscated code

Comment: post your build.gradel file `android.support.v4.widget.i.a` indicated prorogue apply on your apk .

Comment: Please post drawer code.

Comment: Please, provide the build tools version, support library's version numbers.

Comment: Do you have "instant run" enabled in android studio while building the app and release version? Check if disabling this will help. I had the same problem but the app used to crash in kitkat versions, i.e., all versions below Lollipop. Disabling this resolved the issue.

Comment: Use latest support library and build tools version.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting **[NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)** at ***[android.support.v4.widget.drawerlayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)***

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

### How can a NullPointerException launches only on release apk?

> When you prepare your application for release, you configure, build,
>   and test a release version of your application. The configuration
>   tasks are straightforward, involving basic code cleanup and code
>   modification tasks that help optimize your application.

1. Read **[Prepare for Release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html)**
2. set  **`minifyEnabled false`**

You can customise your `build.gradle` like this

```
 buildTypes {


    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false

    }
}
```

Make sure using stable **support library and build tools** .

```
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

**Project Level**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' // or 2.2.2
```

**Then**

> On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart. The
>   Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will
>   be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the
>   dialog to invalidate caches, restart Android Studio .

**Note :** You can provide us your `build.gradle` . Disable `"instant run"` Facility .

.

Answer (score 0):

```
android{
  buildTypes{
     release{
        minifyEnabled false
     }
  }
}
```

Try this in your build.grade.

Or

Try to restart your Android Studio as well as your computer.As is known to all,Android Studio may perform stupid occasionally.

Comment: **Try to restart your Android Studio as well as your computer??**

Comment: Yeah.Sometimes it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using proguard at release,
decrease your gradle version to 2.1.2

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
```

Try this or just clean project and restart the project.
Or Invalidate caches/restart From File Option.
File>>Invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can take to fix these types of errors and make sure your app doesn't crash on future platform updates:

- If your app uses private platform libraries, you should update it to include its own copy of those libraries or use the public NDK APIs.
- If your app uses a third-party library that accesses private symbols, contact the library author to update the library.
- Make sure you package all your non-NDK libraries with your APK.
- Use standard JNI functions instead of getJavaVM and getJNIEnv from libandroid_runtime.so:

> ```
>  AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM -> GetJavaVM from <jni.h>
>     AndroidRuntime::getJNIEnv -> JavaVM::GetEnv or
>     JavaVM::AttachCurrentThread from <jni.h>.
> ```
>
> Use __system_property_get instead of the private property_get symbol
>   from libcutils.so. To do this, use __system_property_get with the
>   following include:

## include

> Note: The availability and contents of system properties is not tested through CTS. A better fix would be to avoid using these properties altogether.
>       Use a local version of the SSL_ctrl symbol from libcrypto.so. For example, you should statically link libcyrpto.a in your .so file, or
>   include a dynamically linked version of libcrypto.so from
>   BoringSSL/OpenSSL and package it in your APK.

Answer (score 0):

According to the android api reference - [Android Developer Api Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html,)

***If your layout configures more than one drawer view per vertical edge of the window, an exception will be thrown at runtime.*** I suspect your drawer layout is incorrect. Also check that the layout gravity of the drawer is set to "start"

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```